# Get port vlan tag via snmp on HP Procurve

Tags: monitoring, hp, snmp, hp-procurve

I'm trying to write a nagios check that will check if a port is a member of (tagged in) a perticular VLAN.

I've discovered the following SNMP location SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.7.1.4.5.1.1.40 for checking a ports untagged vlan membership. But can't seem to find an equivlent for tagged. I guess since it is a one -> many relationship it may be more complicated.

The switches in question are HP Procurve 2920-48G's

Any hints much appreciated

Thanks
Jona

Answer (score 1):

In the brief research I did, it seems that tagged VLANs are not standardised in SNMP.  The [HP-VLAN MIB](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/11/HP-VLAN.html) seems to be necessary for this.  However, it didn't work for me when I tried walking it on an HP 2810-48G. It may work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the [802.1q Bridge MIB](http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/MIBs/IEEE8021-Q-BRIDGE-MIB-200810150000Z.txt):

1.3.111.2.802.1.1.4.1.4.2.1.5 (ieee8021QBridgeVlanCurrentEgressPorts)

"The set of ports that are transmitting traffic for this VLAN as either tagged or untagged frames."

1.3.111.2.802.1.1.4.1.4.2.1.6 (ieee8021QBridgeVlanCurrentUntaggedPorts)

"The set of ports that are transmitting traffic for this VLAN as untagged frames."

I've tested this on a 2920-24G, so it would be very surprising if it didn't work on the 2920-48G.